# TypeError:Cogs must derive from cog

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a discord bot but when I try to start it i get this error
**TypeError:Cogs must derive from cog**
I tried to search on google but ppl who had this error had a different code
https://justpaste.it/9brl5 This is my code and there is a pic of the error
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/95GIr.png1]

Answer (score 1):

The error speaks for itself. It must derive from a cog.

All you have to do is change the following:

```py
class General(commands.Cog):
```

***Maybe also take a  look at the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20cog#discord.ext.commands.Cog) for more clarification.***